# How do I completely remove an old version of Forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I downloaded an old version of Forge then put a mod on it, it wasn't compatible so I deleted Forge from 'versions' and downloaded a new one.

When I opened the Minecraft launcher again, it only showed the old deleted Forge, and when I try to open it, it says

> The version you are trying to play inherits properties of an unknown version

How do I completely remove this old version of Forge so that Minecraft will recognise the new one?

Comment: Did you close the launcher before trying again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using MultiMC.

It allows you to create multiple instances of Minecraft, with or without forge. And it keeps them seperated, so that nothing can interfere with an instance.

It is free and fairly low weight.

Comment: Just reminding: you did not answer the question that CaptainKencel asked. I wouldn't recommend saying just an other option instead of an answer, as this can lead to a badly voted post.

Comment: I know, but with the info provided I wouldn't know what could cause the problem. I also suggest using MultiMC for anybody that doesn't know a lot about their pc, as it keeps every instance nicely encapsulated in their own sandbox. If something does go wrong, it is easy to just remove the instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use this MultiMC, or what, like Robin suggested, you can just go to your folders (assuming you are running on Windows), **search %AppData%** and find **.minecraft** there, or, go to: **C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME*\AppData\Roaming.minecraft** , as this is the default location of **.minecraft** on Windows.

If you are not on Windows (example:Linux), the **.minecraft** folder is usually located in the "Home" folder as a hidden folder, so you should turn on hidden folder visibility.

So, if you found your **.minecraft** folder, go to the **Versions** folder and **delete** the old Forge version folder.

That's it. I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of these methods don't seem to work. Deleting the folder doesn't remove it from the Minecraft launcher. In the most recent Minecraft launcher (2.1.1433), this worked for me:

1. Start Minecraft
2. Click the hamburger menu and then launch options
3. Click forge version you want to remove
4. Click delete in upper right